# What should I do if I don't have all the devices to take graphic captures to upload a new app to PlayConsole?

Tags: google-play-console

I'm trying to upload a new App to Play Console but they are asking for captures from different device types that I don't have.

Phone, 7" Tablet, 10" Tables and from a Chromebook.

I Have a phone but not the rest of devices.

They also ask about something like "graphic functions"(grafico de funciones"), I don't understand what they are talking about.

Everyday they make it more and more complex to upload apps. I'm so frustrated.